# Why the length of tinyint seems to make no difference?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql5.5

I've been searching for what the length in the `tinyint` declaration means (e.g. `tinyint(5)`). And the answers seem to be that it should just be a rule for how MySQL displays the data. But in my case there seems to be no change whichever length i use, or i just heavily misunderstood what they meant.

For example, setting the length to be shorter than the length of the number i store, i thought maybe it would crop it, but it didn't:

```
MariaDB [test]> describe test;
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| hello | tinyint(1) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.002 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select * from test;
+-------+
| hello |
+-------+
|    20 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Then i changed the length to be longer than the length of the number, expected it to be padded to left with zeroes, but again it wasn't:

```
MariaDB [test]> describe test;
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| hello | tinyint(3) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.002 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select * from test;
+-------+
| hello |
+-------+
|    20 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

The version i am using is: `5.5.5-10.3.25-MariaDB-0ubuntu`.

How can i see where this length declaration makes any difference?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, `INTEGER` types are not defined by the number of digits. Instead the number of bytes available to represent the value are declared. E. g. if you define a `TINYINT(1)` you'll get one byte to store the number.

With signed integers this will give you a range of `-128` to `127` while you would get a range of `0` to `255` with unsigned integers:

```
create table test (signed_tiny tinyint(1), unsigned_tiny tinyint(1) unsigned);
insert into test (signed_tiny, unsigned_tiny) values (-128, 0), (127, 255);
select * from test;
+-------------+---------------+
| signed_tiny | unsigned_tiny |
+-------------+---------------+
|        -128 |             0 |
|         127 |           255 |
+-------------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

When you try to insert values out of these ranges, you will get an error message:

```
insert into test (signed_tiny, unsigned_tiny) values (128, 256);
ERROR 1264 (22003): Out of range value for column 'signed_tiny' at row 1
```

It doesn't make any difference if you declare a higher number within the paranthesis of `TINYINT` because it is statically defined to be one byte, so will still get the same error e. g.

```
alter table test modify signed_tiny tinyint(2);
insert into test (signed_tiny) values (128);
ERROR 1264 (22003): Out of range value for column 'signed_tiny' at row 1
```

To avoid this error, you could either use `SMALLINT` which is defined to use two bytes for the value represenatation or use the standard SQL `INT` datatype:

```
alter table test add signed_smallint smallint;
insert into test (signed_smallint) values (128);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
```

According to the [MariaDB TINYINT manual](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/tinyint/) you can add a number in paranthesis but it will make no difference. So `TINYINT` in MySQL and MariaDB is an alias for the standard SQL `INT(1)` and `SMALLINT` another alias for `INT(2)`.

I hope this makes it a bit clearer. Anyway I would recommend to have a look at [the MariaDB documentation.](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/tinyint/)

Comment: I don't know if my question was unclear maybe, but it's about the number in the parenthesis, the `(1)` in your case. If you had created that table in your example with `tinyint(2)` instead of `tinyint(1)`, what would be different? Because i don't notice any difference.

Comment: ah okay, I've added some more explanation, hope it makes it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The `(5)` is useless info except when coupled with `ZEROFILL`.  It is harmless.

MySQL 8.0.19 has removed both.  MariaDB *may* follow suit in a few years.

`FLOAT(m,n)` does mean something, but, in my opinion, it should *never* be used.  It is arguably harmful.  (8.0.17 deprecates it.)

Meanwhile, it is time to move past version 5.5.